# Finding return value of a function in GDB

Tags: c, function, gdb, append

I am very new to using gdb and very new to C programming. There is a line of code in the function I am stepping through that is:

```
append(MACRO, F1());
```

append is just a append string function. I want to know how to find the value of the function F1(). How would I go about doing this. I tried display but then realised it wasnt giving me the correct answer. The output from using display F1 is:

{<text variable, no debug info>} 0x4037bc

Comment: "I tried display but then realised it wasnt giving me the correct answer.": How do you know it was wrong if you couldn't display it?

Comment: Yes I tried display, but realised it was giving me the integer of the address and not the actual value of the function

Comment: @ScottHunter ??

Comment: Figured it out just needed to cast before printing.

Answer (score 1):

first `break F1`, continue to run until F1 is interrupted, and then execute `finish`, then $rax(or $eax) is the return value of F1

e.g:

```
char *F1() {
    return "1234";
}

(gdb) break F1
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1151
(gdb) c
Breakpoint 1, 0x0000555555555151 in F1 ()
(gdb) fin
Run till exit from #0  0x0000555555555151 in F1 ()
0x00005555555551a2 in main ()
(gdb) p (char*)$rax
$1 = 0x555555556004 "1234"
(gdb) quit
```

Comment: If I use `fin`, it already shows me the return value of the function `Value returned is $1 = 0x7ff6f48c4000 "1234"`.

Comment: yes, that's it, If you add the -g option when compiling, will have debug info, which will be displayed. If it cannot be displayed without debug info, you need to look at the register information.

Answer (score 0):

To print the value, it was needed to be cast to an integer first.
E.g. print (int)F1()

Comment: Note that this will cause the debugger to execute the function `F1` an additional time. This is probably not what you want if the function has any side-effects. Because if it does have side-effects, the debugger will be changing the behavior of your program.